# Android : how to know if a user defined a payment method (credit card...) in Google Play?

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing

I would like to know if a user has defined a payment method in Google Play (credit card, Paypal...). Indeed, I don't want to propose paid features to the users if they have no payment method defined. Instead, I want to propose another monetization method like rewarded ads.

How to test if a user is able to pay with its Google Play account ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using InApp billing support then of-course they will have to pay through Google Play.

Comment: Not my question !